# Yii2 using array to build activeform - cannot get & echo second array element

Tags: arrays, yii2

I have created and registered a Yii2 component function 'formSchema' which 
 contains the array as such:

```
class FormSchema extends Component{

  public function formSchema()
  {

    $fields = array(
      ['field' => 'username', 'controltype' => 'textinput'],

      ['field' => 'email', 'controltype' => 'textArea'],
    ); 

     return $fields;
    }
   }
?>
```

I call the array in the active form, however I cannot get the 
 `['controltype']` using the same successful method as I do to retrieve `['field']` as 
 below. I would like to get that array element however seem unable to get any but the first level element:

```
<div class="usermanager-form">

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>$model->formName()]); ?>

<?php

   $fields = $items = Yii::$app->formschema->formSchema();

   foreach($fields as $field)
   {

      $field = $field['field'];

      echo $form->field($model, $field);
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use array values in this way:

```
$fields = Yii::$app->formschema->formSchema();
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    echo $form->field($model, $field['field'])->{$field['controltype']}();
}
```

Comment: >>> Using your example, with thanks. here is an extended example using cited default Yii2 ActiveField widget method details:


    <?php $fields = Yii::$app->formschema->formSchema(); ?>

    <div class="usermanager-form">


    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>$model->formName()]); ?>

    <?php


    foreach($fields as $field)
    {

    echo $form->field($model, $field['name'])->label($field['label'])- 
   >hint($field['hint'])->input($field['input']);

    }

    ?>

Comment: I am a little stuck working out how to format answer posts correctly, this is my first post, any guidance appreciated. There does not seem to be a HTML editor for comments to answers...

Comment: You cannot format code in comments - you may add this as separate answer. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer and https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer